# Take a height. Don't be afraid. Mummy do

Tags: grammar

A mother and a little girl went to clinic.

The nurse is trying to take the little girl height.

The girl was afraid and didn't want to take the height.

> "***Take a height***. Don't be afraid. Mummy do."

the mother told her as she tries to take the height by herself.

Does it sound grammatically correct and natural?

Do we say "take a height" when we measure someone's height?

Comment: In the US we would say "get your height" or, more informally, "see how tall you are."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following for a more natural sound:

"Measure your height"

Additionally you could say:

"Let's measure your height. Don't be afraid. Mummy will do it."

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where we can use **have** or **get**:

> Go ahead, have your height taken (by the nurse).
>
> or
>
> Go ahead, get your height taken (by the nurse).

They are analogous to "have your hair cut" or "get your hair cut".  **Have|get** + something +  past participle. This pattern is used when someone else is doing something for us. We have the choice to say who the other person is in a *by*-phrase. We can add the *by*-phrase or leave it out.

You could also use **let**:

> Go ahead, let the nurse take your height.
>
> Go ahead, let the nurse measure how tall you are.

**Let** + someone +   non-finite clause complement.

Answer (score 0):

The conversation actually **sounds completely natural if the little girl is one or two years old**.

At that age, many of the added words an adult would say are lost on kids and are not used.

> Mommy do

is a key line since a two year old will understand that

> Mommy is doing it also

Comment: The actually grammar after mummy is "does". Is that right?